# Check if vector of strings contains words created from two others words

Tags: r, regex, vector, bioinformatics

I have very very long vector of strings (peptides).

```
head(unique(pseq_list))
#[1] "GPPNHHMGPMSER"  "SLSGQCHHHGENLR" "HSSGQDKPHETYR"    
#"DHDKPHQQSDK"    "AHMESDK"        "HISESHEK"
```

I want to check if in this vector are peptides created by two others peptides. For example if there are `"AHMESDK"`, `"AHME"` and `"SDK"` I want to know that. I tried `grepl` function but probably my vector is to long(?). Also, how to save such results?

If it would be too difficult to verify if there exists `"AHMESDK" = "AHME" + "SDK"` it would be nice to know at least if in the vector are peptides which contains others (for example `"HISESHEK"` and `"SES"`).

---

Context provided by [@quant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3009636) in the comments:

> As a note for everyone without biological background.
>
> Peptides are macromolecules. Our body can compose these macromolecules by "gluing" different amino acids together. The sequence of amino acids glued together is called the primary structure of a peptide and in bioinformatics often the one letter code, see [rpeptide.com](https://www.rpeptide.com/products/amino-acid-codes/) is used in order to represent the primary structure.
>
> So AHMESDK simply means a peptide composed of Alanin, Histidine and so on.

Comment: Can you include the calls to `grepl` which you have already tried?  Not sure what you mean here.  Doesn't searching for `AHMESDK` imply that `AHME` and `SDK` are joined together?

Comment: Please provide reproducible example **and** expected output. It is not very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Data:**

```
pseq<-c("GPPNHHMGPMSER", "SLSGQCHHHGENLR", "HSSGQDKPHETYR", "DHDKPHQQSDK", "AHMESDK", "AHME", "SES", "HISESHEK")
```

Two approaches:

**Approach 1:**

```
peplist<-sapply(pseq,grep, pseq, value=TRUE)
```

Result:

```
$GPPNHHMGPMSER
[1] "GPPNHHMGPMSER"

$SLSGQCHHHGENLR
[1] "SLSGQCHHHGENLR"

$HSSGQDKPHETYR
[1] "HSSGQDKPHETYR"

$DHDKPHQQSDK
[1] "DHDKPHQQSDK"

$AHMESDK
[1] "AHMESDK"

$AHME
[1] "AHMESDK" "AHME"   

$SES
[1] "SES"      "HISESHEK"

$HISESHEK
[1] "HISESHEK"
```

This gives you a list where for every element, you get the list of elements it exists in. We can then create a list of only those peptids that appear within other peptids:

```
peplist[sapply(peplist,length)>1]
```

**Approach 2:**

```
pepcombs<-expand.grid(pseq,pseq) %>%
  apply(1,paste0,collapse="")
pseq[pseq %in% pepcombs]
```

This will give you a list of peptids that can be constructed by combining two of the other peptids.

Comment: Approach 1 works wery well, thanks! Approach 2 would be excelent for me but I try to use it for vector 6000+ length and it is calculating a little bit long and I'm not sure if will be suitable for vectros 1kk+ length. I guess that approach 2 can't bo done faster, right?

Comment: For approach two, the issue may be memory reserves. You could potentially solve it by breaking down pepcombs into a number of smaller vectors, and then looping through them.